# Visual Studio Code: c++ for loop stops before it finshes

Tags: visual-studio-code

I started this question in stack overflow, and after following some suggestions, they deemed it better suited here.

I use Visual Studio code to program in c++, I'm very new. basically, any code that contains a loop stops the loop before it finishes at random intervals, the longer the loop, the more likely for the code to stop.

This is the code I'm using, and yes I am aware that it should work normally.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << i+1 << "- ";
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            cout << 7;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

here are the [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nA1I.jpg).

when I debug the code, I get this: [debug_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSBpo.jpg) [debug_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkTzz.jpg) [debug_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rubMF.jpg)

my assumption is that the thread quits during the loop, which stops the loop entirely.

Someone from stack overflow suggested trying with cmd, surprisingly, it [works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjRpm.jpg) every time. so does powershell. but in vs code, it stops both with cmd or powershell. (note: I added an std::cin to the code to see the result, adding it in vscode activates cin when the loop stops regardless of whether it finished or not)

I did try to run as admin, use a while loop, it didn't change anything, and I do need loops to code.

Comment: why was this migrated to stack overflow? as I stated in the very first line, they deemed it better suited in superuser....

Comment: Why are there multiple threads exiting? The program doesn't look multithreaded. Did you enable some cruel and unusual compiler options? What source files went into `a.exe`? (It should be only `test.cpp`, but you may be linking some other stuff without noticing)

Comment: @dratenik I have no idea why there's multiple thread, and I believe that's what causes the loop to fail, I'm not sure about the compiler options, I just used the reccomended installation procedures. as for a.exe, it only contains test.cpp, itself made solely of the code I provided above. if there were other source files I'd expect a.exe to give unexpected results when opened through cmd as well, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a debugger an set break points.
A debgger allows you to watch inside the variable/memory during the application is running. For example you can set a break point before your `cout` statements  and the dedugger will stop every time before the command will be executed.

A open source debugger is GDB: https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/

Also there are many GUIs for GDB e.g.: https://github.com/cs01/gdbgui/

There are many tutorials out there to use these mighty tool and debugging in general.

Have fun with a new programming experience ;)

Comment: I'm not sure how the debugger is supposed to help here, since the code doesn't work only in vs code's terminal, and the code that I provided is as simple as a loop gets. my problem is that ALL loops in ALL files stop randomly regardless of the directory if they are executed is vs code.

Comment: You are right. Superuser is the better place for this question.